Using VSCode and Prettier, how to have files automatically formatted upon creation?
In my Angular project, when I create new components, the files aren't automatically formatted. I have to manually save each file to apply formatting. Is there a way to configure this so that the files are automatically formatted upon creation?

Not seeing the utility of generating files and never modifying them, but if it's an issue for you, "just" make Prettier run automatically on all added/modified files using a git hook.

Thinking about it!! You're right. I spent too much time on an existential question. Sometimes, one have to go outside of his box to realize that some problems do not worth spending time on them.

There is an open feature request in the Angular CLI for this exact issue.  However it's not implemented yet, so for now you need to apply the format manually.

If you create your files using the CLI. Then you can make use of Prettier CLI. For example you could set it up that it would always run after creating your file.

This works, but I don't think this solution is practicable. Saving the file manually is much easier than running another command with the Prettier CLI. What the author is looking for is to run ng generate ... like usual and have the format applied automatically.

@JSONDerulo would it not be a solution to create an alias to always run prettier after ng ?
